# Error in my response Call List with Retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to get a list of players. I receive the response of Call > 3 Players but in a bizzare format.
I do not know where is my mistake, I search for 5 hours without result.

***ApiClient.class:***

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.sat.sat.Method.FMethod;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by Haytham on 2018-05-15.
 */

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String Base_Url = "https://www.url.com/";
    public  static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Base_Url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
            return retrofit;
        }}
```

***Interface:***

```
    @GET("api/coach/player_list")
 Call<List<PlayerListResponse>> getPlayerList (@Query("token") String Token);
```

***MyActivity:***

```
    ***ApiInterface service = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call <List<PlayerListResponse>> PlayerListCall = service.getPlayerList(FMethod.TokenFC);
    PlayerListCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<PlayerListResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PlayerListResponse>> call, Response<List<PlayerListResponse>> response) {
            int  StatusCode=response.code();
            if (StatusCode==200) {
                Log.d("PlayerList", "onResponse: "+StatusCode+ response.body().toString());
            }
            if (StatusCode==401) {
                Toast.makeText(Coach_list_player.this, "Token"+FMethod.TokenFC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }***
```

***My POJO :***

```
    package com.sweatacademytech.sweatacademy.Pojo;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PlayerListResponse {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("fname")
    @Expose
    private String fname;
    @SerializedName("lname")
    @Expose
    private String lname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("date_assigned")
    @Expose
    private String dateAssigned;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDateAssigned() {
        return dateAssigned;
    }

    public void setDateAssigned(String dateAssigned) {
        this.dateAssigned = dateAssigned;
    }
}
```

And i found in my log.debug: 06-17 16:57:23.007 
200 It's Okey 
[com.sat.sweatacademy.Pojo.PlayerListResponse@2077dfd, com.sat.sat.Pojo.PlayerListResponse@441eaf2, com.sat.sat.Pojo.PlayerListResponse@ed2f543]

Comment: implement `toString` for `PlayerListResponse` and iterate trough `response.body()` using a for loop

Comment: Explain your issue.its not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error

`Call<List<PlayerListResponse>> getPlayerList (@Query("token") String Token);`

Your method return a `List` of `PlayerList`... and log showed exactly this...

`com.sweatacademytech.sweatacademy.Pojo.PlayerListResponse`

If you are worried because you didn't see the actual Players fields at log is because you didn't override `toString()` but this is not an error, is just misinterpretation of you...

by the way you should name better your classes

Comment: How can I better name Classes ?

Comment: There are tons of patterns for class naming you should check online... but it's always good start asking "can someone which never got this code understand the meaning of that?".... you have class which clearly represents a `player` then you named it `playerListResponse` i automaticly think this class is not a player but it is a list of players... by the way it looks you used some pojo generator from schema and this is also a very bad practice